# Are infinite dimensional Lie algebras related to unique Lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups

For every finite dimensional Lie algebra $g$, there is a unique simply-connected Lie group $G$ whose Lie algebra is $g$. Is this true in the infinite dimensional case?

Comment: A side note: in finite-dimensional case for the uniqueness of $G$ you also need to require that $G$ is simply-connected, not just connected.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. Van Est and Korthagen (1964) gave perhaps the first example of what they called a "[non-enlargible Lie algebra](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=160851)", having no corresponding Lie group.

Needless to say, this kind of question largely depends on the precise definitions adopted for infinite-dimensional Lie groups and Lie algebras. A canonical reference is Milnor's [Remarks on infinite-dimensional Lie groups](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=830252), which can be found on the internet and contains also some positive results:

> The author outlines a theory of Lie groups modelled on arbitrary complete locally convex topological vector spaces (CLCTVSs).This category includes everything one would want to call a Lie group, with possibly a few exceptions such as diffeomorphism groups of noncompact manifolds. (...)
>
> Every Lie group as defined here has an associated (topological) Lie algebra. For finite-dimensional groups the converse is true, but ***this is not so in general (even for Banach Lie algebras)***. The passage from Lie algebra to Lie group depends on the notion of regularity. (...) All known Lie groups are regular. A connected, simply connected, regular Lie group is ***uniquely determined (up to isomorphism) by its Lie algebra.***

For a more recent survey I would recommend Neeb's [Towards a Lie theory of locally convex groups](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2261066).

Comment: I appreciate you and your nice solution. thank you

Comment: Is there any  
criterion say that when a lie algebra is lie algebra of a lie group?

Comment: Not that I know of, in general. But see §VI of Neeb's paper for integrability results in special situations, such as e.g. when $\mathfrak g$ is a quotient, or a central extension, of a Lie algebra that is itself integrable (i.e. that is the Lie algebra of some Lie group). The results are most complete when $\mathfrak g$ is "locally exponential", but there are also some negative (*non*-integrability) criteria in general. Do you have access to that paper?

Comment: thank you for your remarkable answer. I have not seen the paper.